# Making multiple CollectionViews programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am having some trouble getting two collection views, side by side in one ViewController.

My issue is NOT with building or displaying the collection views.  Individually, I can get both on the screen as I want them, just not at the same time.

I have debugged my code and found it falls over when setting the ‘cellForItemAt’

I’ve also searched the forums and understand that I need to have an if statement to say…

if collectionView == 1, then dequeue cell A, else dequeue cell B

Unfortunately, when I go to write my if statement, xCode doesn’t find my collection views, i.e. won’t auto find them so I can compile.  Also, I get an ‘unresolved identifier’ for my cell.

Given my efforts above, I have hit a wall and was wondering if anyone could shed some light on my issue?  Thanks

**viewDidLoad code**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    setupCollectionView()   
}
```

**collectionView creation code**

```
func setupCollectionView() {

    let listLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    listLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 40)
    listLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    listLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
    let listFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: 325, height: 500)
    let listView = UICollectionView(frame: listFrame, collectionViewLayout: listLayout)

    // cell
    listView.register(cellA.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellAId)

    // header
    listView.register(headerCellA.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerAID)

    listView.delegate = self
    listView.dataSource = self
    listView.backgroundColor = .cyan

    self.view.addSubview(listView)

    let detailLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    detailLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 40)
    detailLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    detailLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
    let detailFrame = CGRect(x: 330, y: 64, width: 500, height: 650)
    let detailView = UICollectionView(frame: detailFrame, collectionViewLayout: detailLayout)

    // cell
    detailView.register(cellB.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellBID)

    // header
    detailView.register(headerCellB.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerBID)

    detailView.delegate = self
    detailView.dataSource = self
    detailView.backgroundColor = .white

    self.view.addSubview(detailView)
}
```

**cellForItemAt code - can’t get my if statement to work**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

if collectionView == detailView {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellAID, for: indexPath) as! ListCell
} else {  
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellBID, for: indexPath) as! DetailCell
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You need to store a reference to your collection view in a property, not a local variable.  That way you can compare it in the datasource method

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for your comment, it helped re-evaluate my approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately, when I go to write my if statement, xCode doesn’t find my collection views, i.e. won’t auto find them so I can compile. Also, I get an ‘unresolved identifier’ for my cell.**

It is becase you have not defined your collection view globally. You have defined them inside your `setupCollectionView` locally thats why you cant find it in autocomplete.

Comment: No, the collection views are *not* defined globally. They are defined locally inside of `setupCollectionView`.

Comment: @luckyShubhra, thanks for your input.  I re-evaluated how I was going about this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all who commented.  This has been resolved by creating my CV's as a global lazy var closure.

This allowed me to access them in the CV dataSource method and specify different references for my cellForItemAt allowing two CV's to be displayed in the one viewController.

```
lazy var listCV: UICollectionView = {

    let listLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    listLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 300, height: 40)
    listLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    listLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true

    let listFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: 325, height: 500)

    let listView = UICollectionView(frame: listFrame, collectionViewLayout: listLayout)
    listView.delegate = self
    listView.dataSource = self

    listView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

    return listView
}()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

if collectionView == listCV {
   let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: listHeaderID, for: indexPath) as! HeaderCell
   return header     
    } else { ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are the ways you can achive that. Try to do downcasting on your method like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

if let collectionView = detailView as? CollectionViewB {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellAID, for: indexPath) as! ListCell
} else {  
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellBID, for: indexPath) as! DetailCell
    }
    return cell
}
```

> Above will only works if you have two UICollectionView outlets

- Another tweak is you can drag and drop two UIView on your xib
  and then load two UIViewController class each having separate
  UICollectionView object. Whatever the best way you find out implement that first. Just wanted to throw some light on it.